# Using Fourier transformation to reduce the effect of small fluctuation and identify the major trend in Time Series data IN R

Tags: r, series

I have time series data and I want to perform the Fourier transform to determine the pattern of the required time sequence. For each time interval there are small fluctuation and I want to use Fourier transformation to reduce the effect of small fluctuation and identify the major trend for that time interval.

Sample of data:

```
 Date_And_Time ; Temperature
"2007-09-21 10:35:39";"7.480"
"2007-09-21 10:37:39";"7.500"
"2007-09-21 10:39:39";"7.510"
"2007-09-21 10:41:39";"7.520"
"2007-09-21 10:43:39";"7.440"
"2007-09-21 10:45:39";"7.470"
"2007-09-21 10:47:39";"7.560"
"2007-09-21 10:49:39";"7.740"
"2007-09-21 10:51:39";"7.570"
"2007-09-21 10:53:39";"7.730"
"2007-09-21 10:55:39";"7.740"
"2007-09-21 10:57:39";"7.930"
"2007-09-21 10:59:39";"7.870"
"2007-09-21 11:01:39";"7.870"
"2007-09-21 11:03:39";"7.680"
"2007-09-21 11:05:39";"8.160"
"2007-09-21 11:07:39";"8.260"
"2007-09-21 11:09:39";"8.020"
"2007-09-21 11:11:39";"7.900"
"2007-09-21 11:13:39";"7.940"
"2007-09-21 11:15:39";"7.910"
"2007-09-21 11:17:39";"8.040"
"2007-09-21 11:19:39";"8.120"
"2007-09-21 11:21:39";"8.090"
"2007-09-21 11:23:39";"8.140"
"2007-09-21 11:25:39";"8.230"
"2007-09-21 11:27:39";"8.200"
"2007-09-21 11:29:39";"8.380"
"2007-09-21 11:31:39";"8.240"
"2007-09-21 11:33:39";"8.250"
"2007-09-21 11:35:39";"8.340"
"2007-09-21 11:37:39";"8.350"
"2007-09-21 11:39:39";"8.350"
"2007-09-21 11:41:39";"8.350"
"2007-09-21 11:43:39";"8.360"
"2007-09-21 11:45:39";"8.490"
"2007-09-21 11:47:39";"8.560"
"2007-09-21 11:49:39";"8.370"
"2007-09-21 11:51:39";"8.080"
"2007-09-21 11:53:39";"8.150"
"2007-09-21 11:55:39";"8.360"
"2007-09-21 11:57:39";"8.410"
"2007-09-21 11:59:39";"8.590"
"2007-09-21 12:01:39";"8.480"
"2007-09-21 12:03:39";"8.440"
"2007-09-21 12:05:39";"8.420"
"2007-09-21 12:07:39";"8.370"
"2007-09-21 12:09:39";"8.420"
"2007-09-21 12:11:39";"8.420"
"2007-09-21 12:13:39";"8.640"
"2007-09-21 12:15:39";"8.710"
"2007-09-21 12:17:39";"8.880"
"2007-09-21 12:19:39";"8.840"
"2007-09-21 12:21:39";"8.840"
"2007-09-21 12:23:39";"9.420"
"2007-09-21 12:25:39";"8.850"
"2007-09-21 12:27:39";"8.740"
```

For each arbitrary time interval (for example FROM "2007-09-21 11:15:39" TO "2007-09-21 12:19:39" ) I want to extract the trend of temperature.

Expected results is showed below:

[image]

Any suggestion?

Comment: Fourier analysis is not the right tool for the job, since you do not have regular fluctuations. Fourier could be used for smoothing, i.e. lowpass filtering, but there are much more suitable methods to get this. The simplest ideas would be do to a robust linear regression in each interval.

Comment: @DieterMenne, What do u mean by regular fluctuations? Moreover, how irregular fluctuations could cause problem for trend extraction. Would u plz tell number of methods to obtain the trend from time series? Using robust method is so important for me. I will compare the trends from multiple time series in a same time slice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(MASS)
tem = read.table("temperature.csv",header=TRUE,sep=";",as.is=TRUE)
tem$dt =as.POSIXct(tem$Date_And_Time)
plot(tem$dt,tem$Temperature,type="l")

#Overall trend; use dt
coef(rlm(Temperature~dt,data=tem))

#Trend in first range
coef(rlm(Temperature~dt,data=tem, subset=Date_And_Time < "2007-09-21 10:57:39"))
```

Comment: I got this result:                                         (Intercept)            dt 
-1.018678e+05  8.552301e-05 , Would u plz help me to interpret it?

Comment: The second number is the change in temperature per day. The first is an intercept. I suggest doing some reading of ?lm and linear models. rlm is the robust version of it. If your interval does not include a boundary with a slope change, the results should be similar.